# Using Coldfusion to access tyro payment gateway

Tags: java, coldfusion, e-commerce

We are switching our payment gateway to Tyro. Here is the documentation: https://ecommerce.tyro.com/commerce/docs/apidoc/cardToken?api=payments

I am a Coldfusion programmer. Can I get some advice on the best way to implement this in Coldfusion? There are java and PHP examples given, however I only know Coldfusion and I'm not sure which is the best way to get started is.

Comment: Just to add: https://ecommerce.tyro.com/commerce/docs/apidoc/payment?api=payments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to use the Java SDK:

- [Load the JAR files into the CF server](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/integrating-jee-and-java-elements-in-cfml-applications/enhanced-java-integration-in-coldfusion.html)
- [Learn how to use 3rd party Java libraries with ColdFusion](https://cfdocs.org/java)
- Translate the Java examples to CF code.

Doubtful you'll find any examples of how to directly to that with CF. You'll have to find examples of how other 3rd party libraries are used with CF.

You may also check if [they have RESTful APIs](https://www.tyro.com/resources/developer/) that you can use with CFHTTP instead.